# Looking for a criterion for split exact sequence of sheaves of modules similar to Miyata's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Miyata's theorem states that:

> For a commutative Noetherian ring R, and a short exact sequence:
>
> $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow P \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$
>
> if $P$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of $M$ and $N$, then the sequence split.

Is there a similar criterion for sheaves of $O_X$-modules on a variety? Thanks.

Comment: What‘s a Miyata-type criterion? Where is this name from?

Comment: @LukasKofler sorry for confusion. I just mean any similar criterion to the theorem of miyata I quoted. I will edit the question

Comment: Theorem 7.5 in these notes: http://www.math.unl.edu/~rwiegand1/BOOK.pdf @LukasKofler